# Why isn't Django unit test seeing a raised exception?

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-models

I'm trying to test a static method in one of my models but the test is not seeing an exception that's being raised and I don't understand why.

Here's the model and static method:

```
# models.py
class List(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    type = models.ForeignKey('ListType', help_text=_('Type of list'))
    name = models.CharField(_('list'), max_length=128, help_text=_('Name of list'))

class ListType(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(_('type'), max_length=16)

@staticmethod
def read_list(list_id, list_name, owner, list_type):
    try:
        return List.objects.get(pk=list_id, name=list_name, owner=owner, type=list_type)
    except List.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

Here's the test:

```
# tests.py
from django.test import TestCase
from .factories import *
from .models import List, ListType

class TestFuncs(TestCase):
    def test_read_list_exc(self):
        with self.assertRaises(List.DoesNotExist):
            uf = UserFactory()
            lt = ListType.objects.get(type='Member')
            lf = ListFactory(owner=uf, type=lt, name='foo')
            # I've created one list but its name isn't 'bar'
            list = List.read_list(999, 'bar', uf, lt)
```

If I set a debugging breakpoint in the read_list method and run the test, I do see the exception being raised:

```
# set_trace output:
(<class 'list.models.DoesNotExist'>, DoesNotExist('List matching query does not exist.',))

# test output:
...
File "...."
    list = List.read_list(999, 'bar', uf, lt)
AssertionError: DoesNotExist not raised
```

I've read other questions here about how to detect this type of exception and I thought I was doing it right.  Just for fun, I changed the test to the following but that didn't resolve the problem:

```
        ...
        with self.assertRaises(list.models.DoesNotExist):
        ...
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the static method you catch the exception and return `None`.

You could either change the test to use `assertIsNone`.

```
l = List.read_list(999, 'bar', uf, lt)  # don't use list as a variable
self.assertIsNone(l)
```

Or if you really do want the method to raise the exception, then remove the try..except.

```
@staticmethod
def read_list(list_id, list_name, owner, list_type):
    return List.objects.get(pk=list_id, name=list_name, owner=owner, type=list_type)
```

Comment: Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

You already handled `DoesNotExist` exception inside `read_list` so it's not thrown to the test case.

To throw exception you can use `raise` operator:

```
@staticmethod
def read_list(list_id, list_name, owner, list_type):
    try:
        return List.objects.get(pk=list_id, name=list_name, owner=owner, type=list_type)
    except List.DoesNotExist as e:
        some actions to handle exception, for example logging
        ...
        raise e
```